# UITextView scrolling caret to visible text on Device Rotation in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitextview, caret

this scrollToCaretInTextView function was working in Swift 2, but on converting to Swift 3, it has an error message that I can't find a solution to.

Here is the code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var emailBody: UITextView!

     override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
 scrollToCaretInTextView(textView: emailBody, animated: true)
    }

 func scrollToCaretInTextView(textView:UITextView, animated:Bool) {
 var rect = emailBody.caretRectForPosition((textView.selectedTextRange?.end)!)
 rect.size.height += textView.textContainerInset.bottom
 textView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: animated)
    }
```

The error message is:

> Value of Type 'UITextView' has no member 'caretRectForPosition'

How can I fix this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 method signature is changed like [`caretRect(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614518-caretrect)

```
var rect = emailBody.caretRect(for: textView.selectedTextRange!.end)
```

Comment: Can you please add the reason of unaccepting answer as of it is correct and you have unaccepted after 3 months.

Comment: You haven't respond, Can you please care add the reason of unaccepting answer as of it is correct.