# How to get the CGRect of the present caret

Tags: ios, swift

I want to obtain the location of the present caret in `UITextView` as `CGRect`, but there seems to be no information.  Even [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614518-caretrect#parameters), I can't imagine how to utilize this method and find the explanation. Now I could know the way of getting the offset in the `UITextView`, not CGRect. But, I really want to know the `CGRect`.

Any comments should be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. The function in the documentation you linked to already returns a `CGRect`?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was not enough, but what is the argument `for position: UITextPosition`  like?  What should I pass over this method?   In the sense, there is no measurements.  And Now I am experimenting it. However, do you know it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126709/create-uitextrange-from-nsrange ? Is that what you are looking for? The link possible between `UITextPosition` and `UITextView`?

Comment: it is written in Objective-C, I just want to know the way in Swift3.  Even swift 2 seems to be different with Swift 3.

Comment: So, although there are many similar questions here, but my question is new one in the sense.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43321695/1457385

Comment: still can't understand the argument, so I can't use this method properly.   Could you tell me the meaning of the argument?

Comment: Tiny additional information: In the official document, they say the argument is an object that identifies a location in a document.  But to me, how do we fix the location by using the `position`?  Could you give me any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension UITextView {
    var caret: CGRect? {
        guard let selectedTextRange = self.selectedTextRange else { return nil }
        return self.caretRect(for: selectedTextRange.end)
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
let textView: UITextView = ...
if let caret = textView.caret {
    // Do your thing here.
} else {
    // Caret is undefined. 
}
```

---

By the way, you were on the right track :-) The above solution is based on the `UITextInput` method you just mentioned:

```
func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect
```

> Return a rectangle used to draw the *caret* at a given insertion point.

The `UITextPosition` parameter represents a position in a text container; in other words, it is an index into the *backing string* in a text-displaying view.

Comment: Thanks. My problem I tried to solve was already solved, but I am still unclear.  In your the last sentence, what is exactly `a text container`? And I can't also understand the meaning of the `the backing string`.  Could you explain?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita The **backing string** stores the actual text being displayed by the text view, *independently* of how the text is currently being shown in the screen (eg, view width, view height, # of lines, etc). The `UITextPosition` provides a position/index into this backing string. Ex: If the text view becomes wider, the text layout will probably change using fewer lines, *but* a given `UITextPosition` index shoild remaing the same.

Comment: What do you mean by index?   Is it like an array?  How do you assign those indexes toward the backing string you explained?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita Yes, just like array indexes. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34923547/819340) will help further your understanding.

Answer (score -2):

```
//rect is an object of CGRect
var rect = TextView.frame
```

Comment: I want to know the `CGRect` of the caret.  It appears not to work.